# Why wont my code load properly?

Tags: python, class, dictionary, split, load

In class we have to create a save/load function utilizing the split() method for a class and dictionary.  I managed to get the save function working, but the load function does not seem to want to work for me.  I either get it almost working but the saved file does not load, or i get the error

"playerclass" has no "player" attribute.  needs to use the **init** method. Here is the code in its entirety def loaddata(): is mainly the area of concern.

```
class playerclass:
    name = ""
    phone = ""
    jersey = ""
    def __init__(self, name, phone, jersey):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.jersey = jersey
    def setname(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def setphone(self, phone):
        self.phone = phone
    def setjersey(self, jersey):
        self.jersey = jersey

    def getname(self):
        return self.name
    def getphone(self):
        return self.phone
    def getjersey(self):
        return self.jersey
    def disroster(self):
        print("Player Bio")
        print("-----------")
        print("Name: ", self.name)
        print("Phone #: ", self.phone)
        print("Jersey #: ", self.jersey)

def savedata (players):
    filename = input("Enter file name: ")
    print("Saving....")
    outFile = open(filename, "wt")
    for x in players.keys():
        name = players[x].getname()
        phone = str(players[x].getphone())
        jersey = str(players[x].getjersey())
        outFile.write(name+","+phone+","+jersey+"\n")
    print("Save Complete")
    outFile.close()

 def loaddata ():
    players = {}
    filename =input("Enter filename to load: ")
    inFile = open(filename, "rt")
    print("Loading.....")
    while True:
        inLine = inFile.readline()
        if not inLine:
            break
        inLine = inLine [:-1]
        name, phone, jersey = inLine.split(",")
        players[name] = playerclass(name, phone, jersey)
    print("Load Successfull.")
    inFile.close()
    return players


def roster(players):
    if len(players) == 0:
        print("No players on roster: ")
    else:
        for x in players.keys():
            players[x].disroster()

def add_player (players):
    newName=input("Enter name of player to add: ")
    newPhone = int(input("Enter phone number of player: "))
    newJersey = int(input("Enter number of assigned jersey: "))
    players[newName]= playerclass(newName, newPhone, newJersey)
    return players

def ed_player (players):
    oldName = input("Enter players name to edit: ")
    if oldName in players:
        newName = input("Enter new name for player: ")
        newPhone = int(input("Enter new phone number for player: "))
        newJersey = int(input("Enter newly assigned jersey number: "))
        players[oldName] = playerclass(newName, newPhone, newJersey)
    return players

def del_player(players):
    delName = input("Enter players name to delete from roster: ")
    if delName in players:
        del players[delName]
    return players

def displayMenu():
    print("-------Main Menu-------")
    print("1. Display Team Roster.")
    print("2. Add Member.")
    print("3. Remove Member.")
    print("4. Edit Member.")
    print("5. Save Data.")
    print("6. Load Data.")
    print("9. Exit Program.")
    return  input("Menu Choice:  ")

print("Team Management Tools.")

players = {}
menu_choice = displayMenu()
while menu_choice != '9':
    if menu_choice == '1':
        roster(players)
    elif menu_choice == '2':
        players = add_player (players)
    elif menu_choice == '3':
        players = del_player (players)
    elif menu_choice == '4':
        players =  ed_player (players)
    elif menu_choice == '5':
        savedata (players)
    elif menu_choice == '6':
        loaddata ()
    menu_choice = displayMenu()
print("Updating roster Goodbye:")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `players = {}` from your `loaddata` function, and it'll load properly.

If you actually *want* to reset the contents of the dictionary when loading (which might have been your intent, although I would say that's a questionable design decision), you can do:

```
def loaddata():
    global players
    players = {}
    ...
```

This is because any variables you write to are assumed to be local variables (as in, local to the function) unless you say otherwise.

I might be overlooking something, but I'm not seeing anything that attempts to read a `player` attribute from any object, so I'm not sure where the error is coming from. Was it from a different version of this code? Or, if it is the posted version that has that error, can you provide exactly what series of inputs lead to the error?

---

The rest of this answer isn't directly relevant to your question, just some tips based on things I noticed in your code.

I would remove the:

```
name = ""
phone = ""
jersey = ""
```

Because you set them in `__init__` and so they're redundant and not doing anything. For looping over lines in files, you can use a for loop, which is more readable than while loops. Example:

```
for line in infile:
  print(line)
```

And you should look into `with`. It's another type of block, and they're very useful when working with files because they'll automatically close the file when the block ends, so you don't have to. As an example:

```
with open("foo", "r") as stream:
    for line in stream:
        print(line)
# stream got implicitly closed because the block ended
```